# Load libertinus font with libertinus-otf package

Tags: fonts, luatex, libertinus

I am trying to use Libertinus font with Lualatex. I have found so many different suggestions how to do it and finally decided to try the package libertinus-otf. 
It was not included in my texlive distribution (ubuntu 18.04, texlive-full) so I manually downloaded the sty file from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus-otf?lang=en).

This is my document:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twoside=on, titlepage=true, listof=totoc, listof=entryprefix, numbers=noenddot}
\listfiles
%language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

% font, input etc.
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}

\linespread{1.05} %required for palatino, here as well?
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

% further packages: hyperref, cleverref, subcaption, minted, biblatex...

%fault tolerance 
\tolerance 1414
\hbadness 1414
\emergencystretch 1.5em
\hfuzz 0.3pt
\widowpenalty=10000
\vfuzz \hfuzz
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I want the sans serif for the headlines, serif for the text, math for math (obviously), and mono font for code listings. My first question is whether it makes sense this way or whether there is another recommended one? Is the fontspec package even required? It seems to work also without the package.

And am I missing something? Sometimes I have seen recommendations, such as scaling the sans font, changeing linespread etc. Can I assume that it just works for these fonts, since they are in the same package?

My second problem is that I cannot pass arguments to the libertinus-otf package. E.g. `\usepackage[osf]{libertinus-otf}` produces the error:

```
Undefined control sequence \KV@libertinus-otf.sty@osf ...inus@newfigdefaults                                                    \fi  l.50 \ProcessOptionsX\relax
```

This is the shortened output including listfiles:

```
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(u
sing read cache: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic /.texlive2017/
texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.084 seconds
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo(load luc: 
.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-re
gular.luc)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
 (./misc/preamble.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)(load luc: /home
.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-bold.lu
c)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/lmroman10-italic.luc)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luainputenc/luainputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luainputenc/lutf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)))
(./libertinus-otf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-scrlfile.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)
*************************************************
* unicode-math warning: "mathtools-colon"
* 
* I'm going to overwrite the following commands from the `mathtools' package: 
*  
*      \dblcolon, \coloneqq, \Coloneqq, \eqqcolon. 
*  
*  Note that since I won't overwrite the other colon-like commands, using them
* will lead to inconsistencies.
*************************************************
))
./libertinus-otf.sty:50: Undefined control sequence.
\KV@libertinus-otf.sty@osf ...inus@newfigdefaults 
                                                  \fi 
l.50 \ProcessOptionsX\relax

(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/l
ibertinusserif-regular.luc)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luate
x-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusserif-semibold.luc)(load luc: 
.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusserif-italic.lu
c)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/libertinusserif-semibolditalic.luc)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinussans-regular.luc)(load luc:
.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinussans-bol
d.luc)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts
/otl/libertinussans-italic.luc)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinussans-bolditalic.luc)(load luc: /home/fa
bian/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusmono-regul
ar.luc)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/font
s/otl/libertinusmono-bold.luc)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusmono-italic.luc)(load luc: 
.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusmath-regular.lu
c)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/libertinusmath-bold.luc)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-
cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinuskeyboard-regular.luc)(load luc: 
.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/libertinusserifdisplay-re
gular.luc)(load luc: .texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/f
onts/otl/libertinusserifinitials-regular.luc))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-luatex.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lettrine/lettrine.sty
Loading lettrine.cfg
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lettrine/lettrine.cfg))
[..]
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty)
(./doc.w18))
[..]
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-
307.sty) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tracklang/tracklang.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tracklang/tracklang.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries-english/glossaries-english.
ldf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.st
y) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty)))
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)).local/bin/pygmentize

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
No file doc.aux.
*************************************************
* unicode-math warning: "mathtools-overbracket"
* 
* Using \overbracket and \underbracket from `mathtools' package.
*  
*  Use \Uoverbracket and \Uunderbracket for original `unicode-math'
* definition.
*************************************************
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)

[23] [24])This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./doc.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file doc.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in doc.gls.
Transcript written in doc.glg.
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./doc.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file doc.acn...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in doc.acr.
Transcript written in doc.alg.
 [25] (./doc.aux)

 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (type area)
misc/preamble.tex
scrsize11pt.clo    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
polyglossia.sty    2015/03/25 v1.42.4 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and LuaL
aTeX
etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
fontspec.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2018/02/21 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2018/02/21 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018/02/21 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
fontspec-luatex.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
luatexbase.sty    2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
ctablestack.sty    2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
gloss-english.ldf    polyglossia: module for english
luainputenc.sty    2010/11/19 v0.973 inputenc package for LuaTeX
   lutf8.def    2010/05/10 v0.97 UTF-8 support for luainputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
mathtools.sty    2018/01/08 v1.21 mathematical typesetting tools
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
 amsmath.sty    2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
libertinus-otf.sty    2018/06/12 v. 0.07a (Herbert Voss) Supports libertinus fo
nts for all luatex/xetex .
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  ts1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
unicode-math.sty    2018/02/02 vv0.8l Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
unicode-math-luatex.sty    2018/02/02 vv0.8l Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLa
TeX
l3keys2e.sty    2018/02/21 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
filehook-scrlfile.sty    2011/01/03 v0.1 filehook patch for scrlfile package
  fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
lualatex-math.sty    2017/06/15 v1.7 Patches for mathematics typesetting with L
uaLaTeX
microtype.sty    2018/01/14 v2.7a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-luatex.def    2018/01/14 v2.7a Definitions specific to luatex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2018/01/14 v2.7a microtype main configuration file (RS)
lettrine.sty    2015/08/31 v1.9 (Daniel Flipo)
lettrine.cfg
 scrhack.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package 
  xpatch.sty    2012/10/02 v0.3 Extending etoolbox patching commands
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
setspace.hak    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (hacking package setspace)

tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11 `tabularx' package (DPC)
   array.sty    2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
booktabs.sty    2016/04/27 v1.618033 publication quality tables
multicol.sty    2017/04/11 v1.8q multicolumn formatting (FMi)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
subcaption.sty    2016/05/22 v1.1-161 Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
  minted.sty    2017/07/19 v2.5 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 fvextra.sty    2017/07/08 v1.3.1 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
 upquote.sty    2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verbat
im
  lineno.sty    2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifplatform.sty    2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
catchfile.sty    2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
doc.w18
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
  framed.sty    2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
   float.hak    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (hacking package float)
csquotes.sty    2018/02/11 v5.2c context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
csquotes.def    2018/02/11 v5.2c csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
placeins.sty    2005/04/18  v 2.2
paralist.sty    2017/01/22 v2.7 Extended list environments
biblatex.sty    2017/12/19 v3.10 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
alphabetic.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-unicode.def
blx-compat.def    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
standard.bbx    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
alphabetic.bbx    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
alphabetic.cbx    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
varioref.sty    2016/02/16 v1.5c package for extended references (FMi)
hyperref.sty    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hluatex.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for luaTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
bookmark.sty    2016/05/17 v1.26 PDF bookmarks (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2016/05/17 v1.26 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
cleveref.sty    2018/02/08 v0.21.1 Intelligent cross-referencing
glossaries-extra.sty    2018/02/26 v1.27 (NLCT)
glossaries.sty    2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
mfirstuc.sty    2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
    xfor.sty    2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
datatool-base.sty    2017/11/12 v2.29 (NLCT)
  substr.sty    2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
datatool-fp.sty    2017/11/12 v2.29 (NLCT)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
glossaries-compatible-307.sty    2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
tracklang.sty    2018/02/21 v1.3.5 (NLCT) Track Languages
tracklang.tex    2018/02/21 v1.3.5 (NLCT) Track Languages Generic Code
glossaries-english.ldf    2014/11/23 v1.0
glossary-hypernav.sty    2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
glossary-list.sty    2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
glossary-long.sty    2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
glossary-super.sty    2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
supertabular.sty    2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
glossary-tree.sty    2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 english.lbx    2017/12/19 v3.10 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
ltcaption.sty    2013/06/09 v1.4-94 longtable captions (AR)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
 ***********


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                doc
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

)
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 745 words of node memory still in use:
   8 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 1 disc, 2 glue, 1 kern, 9 glyph, 13 attribute, 84 
glue_spec, 13 attribute_list, 1 write, 4 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:6,2:2615,3:178,4:120,5:460,6:1317,7:1389,8:164,9:1258,10:6,11
:332

warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name 'glo:FSS'

warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name 'glo:GPU'
<.local/share/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/libertinusmono-bold
.otf><.local/share/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/libertinusmono
-italic.otf><.local/share/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/liberti
nusserif-italic.otf><.local/share/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus
/libertinusmono-regular.otf><.local/share/fonts/opentype/public/li
bertinus/libertinussans-bold.otf><.local/share/fonts/opentype/publ
ic/libertinus/libertinusserif-semibold.otf><.local/share/fonts/ope
ntype/public/libertinus/libertinusserif-regular.otf>
Output written on doc.pdf (41 pages, 89749 bytes).
SyncTeX written on doc.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on doc.log.
```

Can you tell what is wrong here?

I know that both questions are not that specific, but I hope that you can help me here! Thank you!

Comment: Don't try things in 41 pages document. Start with a small 1-page document and remove everything not directly needed. And don't load the luainputenc package unless you know exactly what it does.  The osf-error looks like a bug in the package. Report it to the author.

Comment: I'll fix it tomorrow

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actully that is kind of what I am trying to do... This should become a 41 pages document, so I tried to figure out, which packages I need and whether the packages I know I will need work together, before I start writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 0.8 is on the way to CTAN. However, in your example there is no
need for loading `luainputenc`. The encoding `utf8` is the deafult.

With the current version 0.8 (http://latex.userpage.fu-berlin.de/libertinus-otf.sty) you'll get with `\usepackage[osf]{libertinus-otf}` the output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating the package! Can you say something about the general usage?
Is the fontspec package required and would you recommend increased linespread or scaling etc.?

Comment: no need for loading any other package. Only xelatex or lualatex are required and, of course, no need for scaling, except the monospace font. This one maybe too wide, a `FakeStretch=0.9` maybe a useful option for this family.

Comment: Thanks, it is great that no furhter adjustments are required and the fakestretch is also already set to 0.8 in the package, if I see that correctly. I have two more question I just post here as comment: 1. What would be the easiest way to switch between options for the font? For example, if I want proportional figures in the text, but monospace figures in tables.
2. What exactly does the the 'defaultfeatures' option do?

Comment: redefine the `\begin{tabular}` that it uses  `\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}` or see page 22 of the fontspec documentation (example 6).