# How to change font style of numbers/caption label and pagenumbers in toc and listofs in Koma-Script?

Tags: luatex, koma-script, fontspec, scrbook

maybe I am asking the wrong question, but I think what I want to do is to change the font style of the numbers / caption labels and the page number in the table of contents and list of tables/figures/abbreviations.

With numbers I mean the "1.1.5" in "1.1.5 This is a subsection ....... 37".
And the page number is then "37". 
With Labels I mean the "Figure 2.23" in "Figure 2.23 Some Figure ...... 49".
And the page number then the "49".

I use lualatex and the scrbook class. The point is that I use proportional, oldstyle figures in my document, but I think that monospace figures would make sense in these two positions in order to get the numbers aligned.

What I did so far is to create a new font family and redeclare the section commands:

```
\newfontfamily\libertinussanstabular{libertinussans}[
  Numbers   = {Monospaced} ,
  Scale     = \libertinusSF@scale ,
  UprightFont    = *-regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-italic,
  BoldFont       = *-bold, 
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic, 
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
  Extension      = .otf  
]

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberformat=\libertinussanstabular\textbf,tocentrynumberformat=\libertinussanstabular\textbf]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberformat=\libertinussanstabular\textbf,tocentrynumberformat=\libertinussanstabular\textbf]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberformat=\libertinussanstabular,tocentrynumberformat=\libertinussanstabular]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberformat=\libertinussanstabular,tocentrynumberformat=\libertinussanstabular]{subsection}
```

As far as I can see there is no way to just use the possibly preferred way with `addkomafont`, since I cannot change sections and subsections there and I don't want to actually change the style of the Heading, but just the entry in the toc/listof.

The approach above works quite well for the toc, but I cannot figure out how to do this a) for the List of Tables/Figures (`\listoftables \listoffigures`).
However, it seems to work for my List of Listings, which I declared with `\DeclareNewTOC`.
b) for List of Abbreviations printed with the glossaries package and \printglossary command.

How can I change those? Or is the whole approach nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

There is no MWE in the question ... so I will use parts of the MWE in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438930/43317) and only answer the question regarding numbers in LoF and LoT.

You can use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` or `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries` for all entry types under control of package `tocbasic`: `figure`, `table`, `section`, ... The options are the same as for `\RedeclareSectionCommand` (or `\RedeclareSectionCommands`) but without the prefix `toc`.

```latex
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[osf]{libertinus-otf}[2018/07/03]
\makeatletter
\newfontfamily\libertinussanstabular{libertinussans}[
  Numbers   = {Monospaced} ,
  Scale     = \libertinusSF@scale ,
  UprightFont    = *-regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-italic,
  BoldFont       = *-bold, 
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic, 
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
  Extension      = .otf  
]
\makeatother

\RedeclareSectionCommands[%
  tocpagenumberformat=\libertinussanstabular\textbf,%
  tocentrynumberformat=\libertinussanstabular\textbf%
]{part,chapter}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
  pagenumberformat=\libertinussanstabular,%
  entrynumberformat=\libertinussanstabular%
]{tocline}{section,subsection,figure,table}%

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\Blinddocument

\captionof{figure}{A test caption for figure}

\captionof{table}{A test caption for table}
\Blinddocument

\chapter{Another chapter}
\captionof{figure}{A test caption for figure}

\captionof{table}{A test caption for table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please ask a new question for the second issue (regarding package `glossaries`) and include there a MWE!