# How to control font in srcbook/KOMA-script table of contents

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, xetex, koma-script, fontspec

I am using XeLaTeX with `scrbook` to produce my thesis. At the moment I am choosing a font combination, however, I found a problem with selecting the font for the table of contents. I cannot control the font of the page numbers for the sections (e.g. 1.1 Overview .... 2).

I want the entire ToC to be my chosen sans-serif font. From the documentation, one cannot set `sectionentry` or `sectionentrypagenumber` for the `srcbook` class. The documentation seems to indicate that `disposition` should do the trick, but it does not. Please see the MWE. I chose the Windows system font Vineta BT to exemplify the problem ... it's not a serious font choice. :)

[image]

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,headings=big,twoside=true,toc=bibliography,toc=listof]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\vineta}{Vineta BT}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\vineta}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\vineta}
\addtokomafont{section}{\vineta}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
Title goes here

{\vineta\tableofcontents}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext

\section{Overview}
\Blindtext

\section{Literature Review}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the macro `\RedeclareSectionCommands` to change the font in the table of contents (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439206/47927)):

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,headings=big,twoside=true,toc=bibliography,toc=listof]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\vineta}{Arial}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[%
  tocentrynumberformat=\vineta\bfseries,%
  tocentryformat=\vineta\bfseries,%
  tocpagenumberformat=\vineta\bfseries,%
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[%
  tocentrynumberformat=\vineta,%
  tocentryformat=\vineta,%
  tocpagenumberformat=\vineta,%
]{section}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
Title goes here

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext

\section{Overview}
\Blindtext

\section{Literature Review}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Sorry, I don't have Vineta BT, so I changed the font to Arial. The header of the ToC is not Arial, but Computer Modern Sans, though.)